# Using a ConcurrentDictionary in webservice

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dictionary

I've built a web service which initializes a set of configuration values from WebConfig like so:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> _configSPSynker {
        get {
            if (_configSPSynker2 != null) return _configSPSynker;
            _configSPSynker2 = (from k in      System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
                               where k.Length > 9 && k.Substring(0, 9) == "SPSynker_"
                               select k).ToDictionary(k => k.Substring(9), k => System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[k]);
            return _configSPSynker2;
        }
    }
```

This dictionary is being used by two different service methods that I have created.

There is actually no issue when calling those methods separately from the test client . however, It's obvious here that it throws an exception when more than one call is made to the webservice!

I happened to come across ConcurrentDictionay in MSDN and wanted to know that If I used this instead , will it solve this problem?

Another point to be noted is that I cannot use a lock because it is static!

Comment: What's the exception to which you refer?

Comment: This is wrong: _I cannot use a lock because it is static!_  You can use a lock and it seems appropriate here.

Comment: @STLDeveloper:It's a stack overflow exception that occurs. I'm suing it like this

(new SPSynker.SPSynkerService(_configSPSynker)).HTVacancy();

Comment: @Silver Mind: Ohkay, My Mentor mentioned that I can't use a lock here because an object is required.. In this case it static. Please could you throw some light on this? How can I place this static Dictionary in a lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, the .NET ConcurrentDictionary class should work for you.  It is a thread-safe dictionary implementation.

You can learn more about the .NET concurrent collections here:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to allow the initialization to happen once in a thread-safe manner is to use Lazy. If the dictionary is read-only after initialization then you don't need to use a concurrent dictionary.

```
static Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>> ConfigSPSSynker = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>>( ()=> LoadConfigSettings() );

static Dictionary<string, string> LoadConfigSettings()
{
 return  (from k in      System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
                           where k.Length > 9 && k.Substring(0, 9) == "SPSynker_"
                           select k).ToDictionary(k => k.Substring(9), k => System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[k]);

}
```

However in your general design avoid statics

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with using a lock object, just make it also static and make sure the code inside the lock is as fast as possible.

I have changed how the dictionary is populated to make it more readable, but that is more of a personal issue. (Seems to fit the answer section better)

Example 1 (Your current situation):

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> configSPSynker;
private static readonly object lockObject = new object();

internal static Dictionary<string, string> ConfigSPSynker
{
    get
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            // check inside the lock, because a race condition can occur.
            if (configSPSynker == null)
            {
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
                foreach (var key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys)
                {
                    if (key.Length > 9 && key.Substring(0, 9) == "SPSynker_")
                        dictionary.Add(key.Substring(9),
                                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]);
                }
                configSPSynker = dictionary;
            }
        }
        return configSPSynker;
    }
}
```

However, I would rather suggest another approach to not expose the dictionary but a method that returns the value for the asked key, because it prevents the caller from accessing and modifying the dictionary:

Example 2:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> configSPSynker;
private static readonly object lockObject = new object();

internal static bool TryGetValue(string key, out string value)
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        // check inside the lock, because a race condition can occur.
        if (configSPSynker == null)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var k in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys)
            {
                if (k.Length > 9 && k.Substring(0, 9) == "SPSynker_")
                    dictionary.Add(k.Substring(9),
                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[k]);
            }
            configSPSynker = dictionary;
        }
    }
    return configSPSynker.TryGetValue(key, out value);
}
```